# Historical Reputation Calculation Error?

Tags: bug, reputation

While looking at someone else's reputation history recently I noticed the following anomaly -- the total for one day was +100, which is **not** the sum of the total activity for the day (+50 and +40). Since the day in question was a long time ago, I doubt that it's because of some pending action that hasn't been fully processed yet, nor do I think it's from a deleted post -- this particular user has made very few of them. 
 In short, it looks like simply a bug.

[image: Screenshot of User John B's Reputation History]

Comment: Got a link for us?

Comment: Since you're looking at rep from 2008, the most likely cause is a deleted post that received an upvote that day. You get to keep rep from deleted posts if the post is over a specific age when it gets deleted (I think it's posts over 60 days old, but am not sure). Also @Bart, [here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/users/9597/john-b?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=4)

Comment: @Rachel: If he kept the reputation from it being deleted, it would still be present in the history, as is the "What is the single most..." post, which is currently deleted.

Comment: @animuson You're right, I forgot deleted posts do show up in rep history :) Perhaps it was something hard-deleted, like the boat question?

Comment: Maybe that was a bonus...